# python keyboard event in raspberrypi

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, keyboard-events

```
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('w'):
        print("You press W!")
        break
```

there is no error, no any reaction
I also tried pigame's keyboard event but got the same result

Comment: What module is providing that `keyboard` object?  And do you actually have a keyboard plugged into your RasPi?  (Remotely logging in via ssh probably doesn't generate keyboard events that the module can detect.)

Comment: import keyboard, I tried it with vnc but it doesn't work

Comment: have you tried directly connecting a keyboard to the raspberry pi?  VNC may not trigger whatever system event the keyboard library is looking for.

Comment: It doesn't work to connect the keyboard directly. What should I do?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? I'm facing the same issue